# How to pass a row of data from a form to another form

Tags: c#

i have 2 form

Form 1 is matching the data . If data is matched with the data in data table then it will load and pass the row of data to form 2.

Form 2 just for displaying the data in text box.

Anyone can help ?

Add on:Because my boss said the message box font size is too small....

Below is my code 
Form1

```
DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();

MySqlCommand com3 = new MySqlCommand("Select EmpNo , PrizeNo , TableNo , Year , EmpName From attendance2018 where Year=3 and Remark!='(Absent)'",con);

MySqlDataAdapter da3 = new MySqlDataAdapter(com3);
con.Open();

da3.Fill(dt3);

List<string> year3 = dt3.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[0].ToString()).ToList();


for (int i = 0; i < year3.Count; i++)
{
    if (year3[i].ToString().Trim().Equals(txtEmployeeID.Text))
    {
        txtStatusInsert.Visible = false;
        picsuccess.Visible = false;
        MessageBox.Show("The following Employee Table number is " + dt3.Rows[i]["TableNo"] + " and Number is " + dt3.Rows[i]["PrizeNo"], "Remind", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();   <----- Do i need to add something to here?
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

form 2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Attendance pass = new Attendance();
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtName.Enabled = false;
        txtPrzNo.Enabled = false;
        txtTableNo.Enabled = false;
        txtYear.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [this google query](https://www.google.com/search?q=winforms+pass+data+between+forms&oq=winforms+pass+d&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5583j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and read.

Comment: I'm curios what is the question title related to your  "box font size" ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll we need to add the variable you want to pass into the parenthesis of the call to the new form like such:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2("variable here");
```

Now in the new form you'll we need to add the variable to the parenthesis of the form constructor as it will be expecting the variable to be passed.

```
public Form2("here")
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtName.Enabled = false;
    txtPrzNo.Enabled = false;
    txtTableNo.Enabled = false;
    txtYear.Enabled = false;
}
```

You can now set elements in the new from to the variable passed from the first. Example:

```
public Form2(type Variable)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtBoxExample.Text = Variable.data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are many ways to achieve this.

On Form 2, you can create a method to get data from Form 1
For example:
Form 1

```
int a = 11;
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
from2.getData(a);
```

Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private int my_number;
    public void getData(int input){
        my_number = input;
    }
}
```

Or simply, just use you Form 2 constructor
For example:
Form 1

```
int a = 11;
Form2 form2 = new Form2(a);
```

Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private int my_number;
    public Form2(int input)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtName.Enabled = false;
        txtPrzNo.Enabled = false;
        txtTableNo.Enabled = false;
        txtYear.Enabled = false;
        my_number = input;
    }
}
```